# Response XML contains " 2000 " and "20a0" characters

Tags: php, xml, sockets, webdav, fgets

I have a WebDAV propfind request sent using PHP. The HTTP request looks like this:

```
PROPFIND /path/to/whatever HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: My Client
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Depth: 1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic bLahDeBlah=
Content-Length: 82
Connection: close

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><propfind xmlns='DAV:'><allprop/></propfind>
```

It works fine when the response XML is less than about 1.5 MB. When the response is bigger, the XML contains characters like `\r\n2000\r\n` and occasionaly `\r\n20a0\r\n`.

I am using this PHP code to retrieve the response:

```
<?php
$output = "";
while (!feof($this->socket)) {
        $output .= fgets($this->socket, 1024);
}
```

I can get around this issue by stripping the unwanted characters from the response - but I'd like to prevent this. Any idea what could cause this?

**Update:** The response header contains `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Our PHP build is Windows and I believe there is no DLL available to use `http_chunked_decode()`.

Comment: The response data is probably due to transfer-encoding being set to chunked by the remote server.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What are the response headers?

Comment: The response header has "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"

Comment: I'm forced to use Windows which means we don't have HTTP extensions and access to using: http_chunked_decode() - I'll need an alternative to http_chunked_decode().

Comment: If you use raw sockets you're forced to rewrite HTTP yourself. PHP has several builtin HTTP clients (from Curl to stream wrappers). Aren't any of them an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people already have pointed out in the comments the "hex"-characters are inserted because of the response being [chunked-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

[This stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793017/how-to-easily-decode-http-chunked-encoded-string-when-making-raw-http-request) deals with the same issue (not using the PECL extension) and suggests the following code-snippet for decoding the response:

```
function decode_chunked($str) {
  for ($res = ''; !empty($str); $str = trim($str)) {
    $pos = strpos($str, "\r\n");
    $len = hexdec(substr($str, 0, $pos));
    $res.= substr($str, $pos + 2, $len);
    $str = substr($str, $pos + 2 + $len);
  }
  return $res;
}
```

As pointed out in the linked question, make sure the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is set before applying the decoding.

*Update:* The Zend-Framework features a [Response](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.response.html) class that also supports chunked decoding. Note that that Zend\Http classes can be used as a stand-alone components (no need to have the full framework included in your app!).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Zend Framework has the function decodeChunkedBody() to do this in the Response Class. Seems to work!